# Does the java RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS affect performance?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in order to solve the following issue: after inserting a row into database and then retrieving its ID by executing a new select, sometimes, the row is not found - somehow the info did not get to the DB.

I am guessing that this flag assures that the data is committed to database before executing the next line of code. If so:

1. does the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` affect performance ? Letting the execution without this flag will perform faster?
2. how does the flag affect SQL statement processing ?

[Edit] - I am using MySQL Server as DB, c3p0 for the connection pool implementation and mysql-connector-java for the driver.
For a glimpse over the context I am referring to, bellow is a code snippet:

```
    StringBuilder insertedId = new StringBuilder("");
    DAOSession session = DAOSession.getInstance();
    Connection conn = session.aquireTransaction();
    Statement stm = null;
    try {
        stm = conn.createStatement();
        stm.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stm != null) {
            // Find and return the generated key
            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = stm.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    insertedId.setLength(0);
                    insertedId.append(generatedKeys.getString(1));
                } else {
                    // Log this scenario
                }
            }

            stm.close();
        }

        conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the database and its driver implementation. It is impossible to generalize this for all JDBC drivers in existence. If you don't want this closed as too broad, at minimum specify the database and driver you use, and consider posting a representative sample of how you use it in your code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the fast reply ! MsSql as DB and c3p0 as a driver. Also added code sample.

Comment: @Victor C3P0 is not a driver. It is connection pool implementation.

Comment: Your code looks very convoluted, and doesn't actually seem to execute anything, and retrieving generated keys in a finally block will lead to problems when exceptions occur earlier in the try block.

Comment: Since c3p0 is not a JDBC driver, are you using Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver or jTDS?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry for misleading - I am using MySql (but have written MsSql). mysql-connector-java for the driver. Also, tried to sanitize the code in order to be clearer and not to cut from its functionality. I also understand that it may not follow the best practices, but I did not want to invest time in refactor, but to understand how is the flag affecting the execution.